# rails: jquery-minicolors-rails for a text_field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, users can choose a profile color. It's basically a string where user put the colors hex. it's that simple.

I installed [gem 'jquery-minicolors-rails'](https://github.com/kostia/jquery-minicolors-rails) to make it a little bit more stylish. Here is a bit of code to explain:

**form.html.erb**

```
 <%= f.text_field :profile_color, as: :minicolors, :class => "minicolor", id: "inputstyle",  class: "form-control", placeholder: "eg: Black or #dde244" %>
```

**minicolors.js.coffee**

```
$ -> $('input[type=text]').minicolors theme: 'bootstrap'
```

It's kinda working, but the problem is that it's adding the minicolors module on every text_field of my app. How can I target only the :profile_color field?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you applied the id of `inputstyle` to the text field, you can simply access it by its ID:

```
$ -> $('input#inputstyle').minicolors theme: 'bootstrap'
```

That would apply the plugin to that single text field.